# How to deselect "Grant Access Using Hierarchy" OWD setting for a custom object which is controlled by any other Parent object?

Tags: apex, role-hierarchy, owd

I have a use case where I have a custom object which have a master detail relationship with account object and due to this its OWD sharing setting are controlled by account object, Since account is a standard salesforce object and it have "Grant Access Using Hierarchy" checkbox selected by default and we can't change it.

So I just want to know is there any way to deselect the required sharing setting checkbox on my custom object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change any sharing settings for a detail object in a master-detail relationship. This includes its organization wide default access levels, shared by hierarchy setting, sharing rules, etc.